# Directional derivative for non differentiable function?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

How may I find the Directional derivative for this function if it's not differentiable at (0,0).

Which means I can't use: $\frac{\partial f}{\partial v} = \nabla f \cdot v$

$$f(x,y)= \begin{cases}
\frac{x^2y}{x^4+y^2}, & (x,y) \ne (0,0) \\
0, & (x,y) = (0,0)
\end{cases}$$

Note: I tried to write the function here but failed since it has two cases.

Comment: How do you know it's not differentiable?

Answer (score 2):

By definition, the partial derivative at $(0,0)$ with respect to the direction $v$ is the limit$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(hv)-f(0,0)}h.$$So, compute this limit.

Comment: But how to multiply h by point? for example v is (1,2) do we multiply it by 1 and by 2?

Comment: Yes: $h(1,2)=(h,2h)$.

Comment: Given that v = (-1,1), we get:
$$
\frac{f(-h,h)-f(0,0)}{h}=\frac{h^3}{h^4+h^2}
$$
if h goes to zero then the lim is 0 which is wrong

Comment: Why do say that it is wrong? It looks right to me.

Comment: I submit the answer on online website and it tells me it's wrong, I was given to calculate that when the direction's $v$ angle with positive x axes is 135 so I took the point (-1,1)

Comment: any hint on what's wrong here?

Comment: My bad. We have$$\frac{f(-h,h)-f(0,0)}h=\frac{h^2}{h^4+h^2}=\frac1{h^2+1}$$and therefore the limit is $1$. Unless (as I suspect) the author of the question wants you to use an unit vector, in which case you should use $\frac1{\sqrt2}(-1,1)$ and the answer will be $\frac1{\sqrt2}$.

Comment: Yes that's were I made mistake, But why should I use unit vector and not any vector?

Comment: Because if you are only interested in the *direction*, that's the natural option. Otherwise, why $(-1,1)$ and not $(-14,14)$ or $(-2\pi,2\pi)$?

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider
$$f(x,y)= \begin{cases}
\frac{x^2y}{x^4+y^2}, & x^2+y^2 \ne 0 \\
0, & x=y=0
\end{cases}$$
This function have derivative on any line which contain $(0,0)$, because it's $0$ on both axis and for points $(x, kx)$ it is $f(x,kx)=\frac{kx}{x^2+k^2}$. But is not even continuous there by approaching $(0,0)$ on points type $(a, a^2)$, as equals $\frac{1}{2}$.